# c++ map large numeric string to numeric string ranges

Tags: c++, string, optimization, range, numeric

I have to write a C++ function where the input is a 12 digit numeric string. I have to find the range which is also stored in string arrays.

For Example,

Range array [10]: 
1 - 111115555522 - 111225555521 
2 - 111225555522 - 111335555521 
3 - 111335555522 - 111445555521 
4 - 111445555522 - 111555555521 
5 - 111555555522 - 111665555521 
6 - 111665555522 - 111775555521 
7 - 111775555522 - 111885555521 
8 - 111885555522 - 111995555521 
9 - 111995555522 - 112005555521 
10- 112005555522 - 113005555521

Input  - **111555512440** 
Output - the number belongs to range - **5**

I have used "long long" data type for numerical ranges and the input as well and accomplished it. But since I have to also maintain performance, can somebody give me a better idea to make it such that input value remains string as well as the ranges will also remain in string?

P.S.: I am fine with the use of "char" pointers instead of std::string.

Comment: `long long` will be faster than strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a string, except when converting any input data. That will be orders of magnitude slower than using integral types. Instead, maintain the range posts in a `std::vector<std::uint64_t>`.

Noting that your vector will be sorted, use `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound` to get the range in which a given number can be found. These functions operate O(log N) and so are fast. Do read up on the subtle differences between those functions.

(Note that `std::uint64_t` is *always* a 64 bit unsigned integer and so is good for 12 digits, but note that a C++ compiler does *not* necessarily have to support it; although it's been a very long time since I've come across one that doesn't.)

Comment: can you write an example if possible?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to make a for loop and go through the string starting from the left, eliminating options on the way. In your example, the first two digits don't eliminate anything, then the next digit eliminates range 10 since the input is bigger smaller than the lower bound of the range, then the next digit lowers the range down to either 4 or 5, and the next digit determines the range to be 5. You don't have to go through the entire string usually, which is good for performance if you will be doing this a number of times. The atoi() function will come in handy when converting the individual digits to ints.

Example: let's say you're storing the ranges in an array, number_ranges[10], where number_ranges[0] is the lower bound of the first range, number_ranges[1] is the lower bound of the second range (and anything below it is still in the first range), etc. Let's also have an arrays of booleans, possible_ranges[10], where true means that a range is still possible, while false means it's not. Since we haven't eliminated anything before starting, everything should be set to true. Now, we need to go through each string, and eliminate ranges as appropriate.

```
for (int i = 0; i < (length of input); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < (number of ranges, which is ten); i++ {
        if (input[i] is less than number_ranges[j][i], then there is no way we're in that range, so make that range false)
        if (input[i] is greater or equal to number_ranges[j][i], then there is no way we're in the range below it, so make that false)
        if (everything is false but one, you have your answer, so return it)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean starting from left most digits? Can you explain a little bit more with sample if possible?

Comment: Ok, I've added an example. Let me know if it still isn't specific enough.